# matching pattern in python before it reaches a certain character

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a scenario where I have two strings to check for a match but the matching should be happening until a specific character (in my case `-`) is found.
here is what I am doing with a positive look forward approach but it doesn't seem to work

```
txt1 = "ap1-tempora1yu"
txt2 = "ap1-gt4"
if re.search(".+?(?=-)", txt1) == re.search(".+?(?=-)", txt2):
    print("found")
else:
    print("not found")
```

I have also tried this regex patterns but no luck `/^(.*?)-/` and `/.+?(?=-)/`
any help woud be great

Comment: you could use the `.split()` string method to get everything in the string before the '-' without using regex. txt1.split('-')[0] == txt2.split('-')[0]

Comment: If you must use regex, you can also use `(.*?)-` and then grab group 1

Answer (score 0):

As @oh_my_lawdy commented, you don't really need regex here. However, if you want to use it then the issue with your code is that `re.search()` returns a [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects). For such objects even the value of the expression

```
re.search(".+?(?=-)", txt1) == re.search(".+?(?=-)", txt1)
```

(with the same string `txt1` on both sides) is `False`. What you should compare instead are the actual substrings matching the pattern. These can be obtained using

`re.search(".+?(?=-)", txt1).group(0)`

More precisely, this returns the first match group, but this is the only group in this case. In effect your code can be modified as follows:

```
txt1 = "ap1-tempora1yu"
txt2 = "ap1-gt4"
if re.search(".+?(?=-)", txt1).group(0) == re.search(".+?(?=-)", txt2).group(0):
    print("found")
else:
    print("not found")
```